# Check null objects after passes as parameter

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, null

I need to check if some objects are null and Im wondering if there is an easier solution to my problem.

Basically I need to put some values in a hashMap but some the value references may be null.

to solve this problem  I have the following

```
if (object1.data != null) {
   map.put("key1",object1.data.value);
} else {
   map.put("key1","NA");
}
if (object2.data != null) {
   map.put("key2",object2.data.value);
} else {
   map.put("key2","NA");
}
if (object1.otherData!= null) {
   map.put("key3",object1.otherData.value);
} else {
   map.put("key3","NA");
}
if (otherObject.otherData != null) {
   map.put("key4",otherObject.otherData.otherValue);
} else {
   map.put("key4","NA");
}
```

And there are a lot more values that I need to add to the map, all values are Strings, but the Objects, and Data are different.
As you can see,  this is simple checking if the Data is not null I'll get its value, but I'll need to do this for 1000+ values.

I was thinking of something like:

```
public String getValue(Object myObject) {
if (myObject == null) {
return "NA"; 
} else {
return myObject;
}
}

and call it like:

map.put("key1",getValue(object1.data.value));  // this of course wont work, when data is null
```

Anyone have any idea how can I improve this?
I tryed terniary if,  but its not really readable. Im looking for another solution if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator looks neat to me:

```
public String getValue(Data data){
    return Objects.nonNull(data)?data.value?"NA";
}
```

And use it like below:

```
map.put(key, getValue(object.data));
```

Comment: This looks good,  unfortunately _It wont work for:
    data.otherData 
    data.diferentVariableName

could it be possible to pass the variable name as parameter?

Comment: @Marcopolo Ramos is your otherData and differentVariableName are of same type? If yes, then you don't have to worry it will work. If no, then you can pass Type of that variable as parameter and typecast and then call value.

Answer (score 1):

You could write map wrapper and incapsulate your logic there, for example:

```
public class ExampleWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public ExampleWrapper() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void putIfDataNotNull(String key, String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            map.put(key, data);
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return map.getOrDefault(key, "NA");
    }
}
```

Or you can put `"NA"` value immediately after checking for `null`

Also you can write overloaded methods like this:

```
public void putIfDataNotNull(String key, Data1 data) {
    if (data.getValue() != null) {
        map.put(key, data.getValue());
    }
}

public void putIfDataNotNull(String key, Data2 data) {
    if (data.getAnotherValue() != null) {
        map.put(key, data.getAnotherValue());
    }
}
```

But many things depends on your next logic. How you use this **map**, and what's you need specifically. What role does this **map** have?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps send the `data` instead, because that's what you worry might be null.

```
public String getValue(Data data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return "NA"; 
    } else {
        return data.value;
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
map.put("key1", getValue(object1.data));
```

Comment: This is good in case, "value" is always the attribute name,   but what is there are different attribute names,   maybe its possible to give the attribute name as  a parameter?

Comment: That might be possible, sure.  Although if your function is named `getValue` that implies you're getting `value`, so you might want to rename it if it's getting various things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this:

```
map.put("key1", object1.data != null ? object1.data.value : "NA";
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you access object's members directly, but if it's possible to add getters then you can do something like:

```
public static String getOrDefault(Supplier<Data> supplier) {
    Data data = supplier.get();
    return data == null ? "NA" : data.value;
}
```

and then safely populate the map:

```
map.put("key1", getOrDefault(object1::getData));
map.put("key2", getOrDefault(object2::getOtherData));
```